When we can say that $\mathrm{soc}(R) = \mathfrak{m}^n$?
The socle of a local ring $(R, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ is defined as the colon ideal $\mathrm{soc}(R) = (0:\mathfrak{m})$. My question is:
Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be an artinian local ring with $\mathfrak{m}^{n+1} = 0 $. It's easy to see that $\mathfrak{m}^n \subseteq \mathrm{soc}(R)$.
When we can say that $\mathrm{soc}(R) = \mathfrak{m}^n$?

It need not always be.  For instance take $k[x,y]/(x^2, xy^2,y^3)$. I'm not sure there is a nice description other than it happens when it happens

It's true for self-injective $R$.

More generally it's true whenever your $(R, \mathfrak m)$ has a unique minimal ideal. Being self injective (=QF in this case) is a special case of that.  It all boils down to whether or not $\mathfrak m^n$ contains all copies of the unique simple module lying in $R$.

@rschwieb, are you assuming commutative? Actually it’s not clear if the question assumes commutative although it is tagged that way.

If $R$ is Gorenstein, then the socle is simple, so the minimal nonzero ideal of $R$. Since $\mathfrak{m}^n \neq 0$,  it must equal the socle. This is basically following up on the comments of Dave Benson and rscwieb.

@BenjaminSteinberg You're right, the question is tagged [ac.commutative-algebra], so i assumed it was the case :/

@BenjaminSteinberg Regardless the criterion about having a unique minimal right ideal or unique minimal left ideal is still an indicator, since either one would be contained in $\mathfrak m^n$.  And a local QF ring has both, and they actually coincide...

Thanks everyone  for your kind help.
